# outlook.com api event creation date

Tags: php, api, rest, outlook

I am working with `PHP` and `Outlook REST API`, I am able to create the events just fine except that the `date` I give API to create events is getting incremented by 11 hours and something is wrong with `end_date` also, for example if i am telling the API to create the event from `2014-03-31T15:00:00-0000` to `2014-03-31T16:00:00-0000` it ends up creating the end from `2014-04-01T02:00:00+1100` to `2014-04-01T02:30:00+1100`

This is what my API URL looks like

```
https://apis.live.net/v5.0/9898ef90931244e8/events?name=testing_event&description=event_description&start_time=2014-03-31T15:00:00-0000&end_time=2014-03-31T16:00:00-0000&access_token=token-goes-here&method=POST
```

if I remove the -0000 at the end, i get the following error

```
{
   "error": {
      "code": "request_parameter_invalid", 
      "message": "The value of input parameter 'start_time' isn't valid. The expected formats for this parameter are the following: '1970-01-01T00:00:00Z', '1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z', '1970-01-01 00:00:00Z'. In all cases, 'Z' is interchangeable with a time zone offset of the form: '+00:00', '-00:00', '+0000' or '-0000'."
   }
}
```

I will really appreciate any help as I have spent hourssss trying to fix this and I am pretty much out of all ideas..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A while ago I posted this question at MSDN Forum and forgot about it, today i visited the question and this is the [reply](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f902994b-f8cb-4d5b-a763-43f3d10ea2ce/outlook-rest-api-adding-event-date-issue?forum=messengerconnect) I got from Outlook team explaining how to understand UTC timezone, I hope this helps someone out there stuck at the same problem and I wish they included this in their documentation. This fixed the problem I was having

> *The ISO 8601 format for dates can be a bit confusing. What you're seeing in your response is actually correct. The calendar service
>   takes your date and maps it to the time zone of the user.
>
> "2014-03-31T15:00:00-0000" means 3 PM on March 31, 2014, with an
>   adjustment of 0 hours and 0 minutes to translate to UTC time. In other
>   words, this basically IS UTC time. The calendar service then
>   translates this into the local time zone of the user for whom you are
>   creating the event. "2014-04-01T02:00:00+1100" means 2 AM on April 1,
>   2014, for whatever time zone your user is in. To translate back to
>   UTC, you need to SUBTRACT the offset from the local time. So 2 AM,
>   April 1, 2014 in your time maps to 11 hours earlier UTC, which is 3 PM
>   March 31, 2014 (what you entered).
>
> If you're using Z, that means that you are essentially specifying a
>   UTC time. So to get the desired time for your event you need to take
>   your desired time and figure out what the corresponding UTC time is.
>   So if the UTC offset of your user is +1100 you would need to subtract
>   that offset from the local time of your event to calculate the UTC
>   time. In your case I believe this would be 2014-03-31T04:00:00Z. This
>   is actually something that's best left to code instead of trying to
>   figure out how to do yourself. If you take a look at the "Creating
>   Calendar Events" sample at http://isdk.dev.live.com it shows you how
>   to do this in JavaScript - maybe there's a PHP equivalent.*

Answer (score 1):

Try using Z for local time like this:
2014-03-31T15:00:00.000Z

So it would be something like

> https://apis.live.net/v5.0/9898ef90931244e8/events?    name=testing_event&description=event_description&start_time=2014-03-31T15:00:00Z&event_start_time=2014-03-31T16:00:00Z&access_token=token-goes-here&method=POST

Comment: this does not have any difference, still adds +1100

Comment: From API page:Times must end in one of these formats: +hhmm, -hhmm, +hh:mm, -hh:mm, or Z, which represents the number of hours and minutes as an offset to, or in coordination with, UTC. For example, -0700 represents seven hours preceding UTC. If this time is combined with the preceding example, the result is 2011-05-10T14:29:00.000-0700, or 10 May 2011, at 7:29 A.M.
Note  If Z is not specified, the time is treated as local time. Also, if end_time is not specified, the default end time is 30 minutes after the specified start_time.

Comment: On your original post you are also missing the .000: 2014-03-31T16:00:00-0000 shoud be 2014-03-31T16:00:00.000-0000 althout the -0000 dont know if works try -0100

Comment: nope, still adds 11 hours, i gave the API `start_date: 2014-03-10T14:00:00.000-0700` and end_date: `2014-03-10T14:30:00.000-0700` and the API added the event from `2014-03-11T08:00:00+1100` to `2014-03-11T08:30:00+1100`

Comment: When you go to the calender does it appear with that date or it shows the date you wanted. It might just be that is saves on that timezone and then on the calendar it shows depending on your timezone.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same time with a different time zone (the -0000 and +1100).

Comment: how can i stop it from adding this then? I just want the API to create the end for the exact time i give it

Comment: Well, I'm no expert on the Outlook REST API, but I imagine that /9898ef90931244e8 is in the time zone +1100. You probably need to specify that time zone in the date you send up, or Outlook will convert it for you (incorrectly).

Comment: I have tried several ways to give timezone but none of them work, no matter what timezone i give it, it will adds 11 hours to it